# Map EC2 Elastic IP to VPC Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

My DNS points to an EC2 Elastic IP and I want to start using a new VPC Elastic IP instead. Is it possible to route the EC2 Elastic IP to the new VPC Elastic IP within AWS such that when I update the DNS, the old IP will continue to work?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately you can only map it to an instance.

Comment: Please feel free to add that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Unfortunately you can only map it to an instance.